# Do the 'Explosive Launcher' and 'Heavy Weapon' cards stack?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

In Horde mode, the Heavy class has a few cool cards, two of which are:

- [Explosive Launcher Damage](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/cards/my-cards/LauncherDamage)  -  Any explosive launcher (Boomshot, Dropshot, RL-4 Salvo, Torque Bow) you are carrying does more damage based on the level of this card.
- [Heavy Weapon Damage](https://gearsofwar.com/en-us/cards/my-cards/HeavyDamage) - Any heavy weapon (Trishot, Buzzkill, Mulcher, RL-4 Salvo) you are carrying deals more damage based on the level of this card.

I was wondering, since both of these increase the damage of the [RL4-Salvo](http://gearsofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Salvo_Rocket_Launcher), do these damage increases stack on this weapon, or does having both the cards active at the same time render one useless?

Comment: Do you have the ability to have 2 cards on at once yet? If you do, put both on and pick up an RL4-Salvo.  Near the icon that shows how much ammo you have, youll see percentages of your boosts from the class cards. If they are stacked, or it shows two percentages, then you have your answer.

Comment: @TimmyJim ahh, neat thanks for the tip! I'll test it tomorrow and post what i find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that the two cards **do** stack.
I went into a custom game with the two cards on and the bonus shown beside the RL4-Salvo was the amount of my first card plus my second card (20% + 40%, 60% was shown).
Thanks to [TimmyJim's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/293670/do-the-explosive-launcher-and-heavy-weapon-cards-stack#comment414843_293670) for pointing out that the bonus is shown beside the weapon when you first pick it up.

Comment: That must make for one heck of a time!  I'll add that if you build a weapon locker and put any weapon into it, it will refill its ammo (including heavy weapons like the RL4-Salvo).  You can only do this a few times before the weapon lockers breaks.  However, I believe you can repair the locker to prevent it from breaking.